# Image and media banks for user content in Plone

Tags: image, plone

This might be more of a user question rather than a developer question. but developers should be able to offer insights.

For the person creating and editing content, what's the best practice for where to store images associates with pages? (I'm referring  to the Plone folder, not the file system directory).

Should it be stored inside the  same folder as the content item itself?  Or a subfolder within the working directory? Or a special directory writeable by all for storing images?

If you do some sort of shared image upload Plone folder, what would the permissions on that Plone folder  be? Once again, I'm referring of course to the Plone folder, not the file system directory.

I see that in the site admin TinyMCE options you can configure some default paths for image uploads. How would you do it so that the user  won't be overwhelmed by all the images in a common images folder? (in other words, he can see and edit only his own image uploads).

Comment: Can't find answers to all this questions: it's only a matter of users preferences, I see no "best solution" there.

Image in the same folder is ok, image in a subfolder is ok and also a global image directory. Your users could give you what they prefers.

About permissions: again, it depends. A "can add" permission in a global image folder can be good, so every users can add and manage own images.

Comment: For multilingual site you want one shared image folder with language set to neutral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is truly a serious weakness in Plone, in the sense there is no "Best or More Oftenly Recommended Way". As @keul highlighted, Plone is flexible enough to support almost every imaginable usecase, nevertheless I can't see much of a consensus - neither a set of common steps - to fulfill the common usecase you described, in a hierarchical-and-permissioned paradigm.

That said I recommend you to check and share opinions, feature requests and code on the second of these:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.ImageRepository
- https://github.com/plone/plone.app.mediarepository

Both focus on easing the use of tags to manage the overwhelming of items you described. I believe this kind of problem would mostly arise when adding images inside TinyMCE sessions, say, adding a News item. However if you just need to update images for sections or the homepage I recommend you to take a look at collective.cover:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_rsSL1e4i4

btw I also recommend you to check these solutions for richer image handling:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.imagecropping
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.ImageEditor
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unweb.iptc/